# In Node.js How to establish timeout call back for each child process created dynamically?

Tags: node.js

Say I have a loop that creates a child process per iteration, how does one create a timeout call back function per child, or maybe one function that can service all child processes?

```
var theSpawn = require("child_process").spawn;
for (var i=0; i<4;i++) {
      theChild = spawn('ls', ['/']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the separate callbacks.  The child process object that `spawn()` returns is an eventEmitter and it supports a number of events:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
for (let i=0; i<4;i++) {
      let child = spawn('ls', ['/']);
      child.on('close', () => {
         console.log(`child ${i} closed`);
      });
}
```

If you're trying to create some sort of timeout for each child, you can do that in the loop:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
for (let i=0; i<4;i++) {
      const child = spawn('ls', ['/']);
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`Hit timeout on child ${i} before it closed`);
      }, 10 * 1000);
      child.on('close', () => {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          console.log(`child ${i} closed`);
      });
}
```

Comment: Yes, a timeout handler per each child is the need.  Thanks for the example.  I sub-classed the timeout function, as well as the spawn task, and got what I desired.  I keep an object populated with the child handles and timeout handles.